# Most efficient way to transform pandas dataframe with relational data to probability linkage

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot

Given is a typical pandas dataframe with "relational data"

```
|--------------|------------|------------|
|   Column1    |  Column2   |  Column3   |
|-------- -----|------------|------------|
|    A         |      1     |     C      |
|--------------|------------|------------|
|    B         |      2     |     C      |
|--------------|------------|------------|
|    A         |      2     |     C      |
|--------------|------------|------------|
|    A         |      1     |     C      |
|--------------|------------|------------|
|    ...       |    ...     |    ...     |
|--------------|------------|------------|
```

I am trying to calculate the probabilities between all column values with length 2, meaning the tuple `(A,1) --> 0.66`, `(A,2) --> 0.33`, `(B,2) --> 1`, `(2,B) --> 0.5` and so on.

I am expecting the result back in a list similar to:

```
[
   [A,1,0.66],
   [A,2,0.33],
   [B,2,1],
   [2,b,0.5],
   ...
]
```

Currently, my approach is really inefficient (even while using multiprocessing). Simplified i am iterating over all possibilities without any Cython.

```
# iterating through all columns
for colname in colnames: 
    # evaluating all other columns except the one under assessment
    for x in [x for x in colnames if not x==colname]:
        # through groupby we get their counts
        groups = df.groupby([colname,x]).size().reset_index(name='counts')
        # for each group we
        for index,row in groups.iterrows():
            # calculate their probability over the entire population
            # of the column and push it in the result list
            result.append([row[colname],row[x],(row["counts"]/df[x].count())])
```

What is the most efficient way to complete this transformation?

Comment: thanks @ALollz! I replaced column3 with different values to avoid this misunderstanding. I meant B from column1

Comment: Your code below does not produce the sample result. Can you post a real sample data with desired result?